# I can't get several common shortcuts to work in VS Code 1.6 for Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Brand new Windows 10 installation. Fresh install of VS Code 1.60. Launched vscode with a dot net core project template, thusly:
`dotnet new webapi -n MyProject`

I added the following extensions:

- .NET Core Tools v0.0.4
- C# for Visual Studio Code v1.23.15
- Visual Studio Keymap v0.2.1

After adding a public interface I set about creating a class that implements it. I expected to be able to position the cursor on the name of the interface being implemented, after the colon in the class declaration, as in `public class MyInterfaceRepo : IMyInterfacerRepo` and hit Ctrl+. to implement the interface, but I'm getting nothing.

Then I also realised that I wasn't even getting Go To Definition or Go To Declaration in the context menu when right-clicking any property. These menu options are also permanently diabled in the Go menu.

I have made sure that the extensions are enabled and experimented with disabling the C# For Visual Studio and/or Visual Studio Keymap extensions.

I've done some research but haven't found a duplication of this specific issue. I have a found C/C++ user that simply had to enable a previously disabled C/C++ for Visual Studio Code extension. This is the C/C++ equivalent of my C# extension, so it sounds as though this is where the magic happens, but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to be sure that VS Code is opening your .csproj file, not simply the folder that the project resides in. This way the extensions will know that it's a C# project and function correctly.